# Compare calling data from Stored Procedures and .NET 'Entity' objects

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, memory, metrics

I would like to know what's the best (fastest) way to gain in performance (memory usage, cpu, ...) between these:

1. You only create a `.dbml` or a `.edmx` file then you call a list of entities as follows

   ```
   MyEntitiesDataContext db = new MyEntitiesDataContext();
   var models = db.Labels.ToList();
   ```
2. You create a stored procedure, you drag/drop it on your `.dbml` / `.edmx` file then you call it as follows

   ```
   MyEntitiesDataContext db = new MyEntitiesDataContext();
   var models = db.ListLabelProcedure();
   ```

This second way of coding is a further work because you need to develop stored procedures by yourself.

PS: We are working with big data. The smallest table can register up to 10G. rows

Can anyone tell me what is the best approach?

Comment: It was my bad! I edited...

Answer (score 0):

All depend on what you need to do with your datas... if you really need them .Net Server side I think both approaches are similar. But if you can process them SQL Server side with a stored procedure, then only retrieve the result, the stored procedure approach would be a good idea.

Moreover I think you should be carefull with the Linq .ToList() because it will "load" all the datas from your SQL Server (network and memory usage), so if you have huge tables, it will impact your ASP.Net Server's memory, where the call to the stored procedure won't.

I hope this will help a bit

Comment: yeah thank you! About the Linq .ToList(), It was an example. usually I use PaginatedPage Class...